# Deletar pasta firebase web

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-storage

Como deletar uma pasta do storage?

Para deletar um arquivo eu uso:

```
firebase.storage().ref('pasta/arquivo.png').delete()
```

Porém não funciona se eu usar direto na pasta:

```
firebase.storage().ref('pasta').delete()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [documentação](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/delete-files?hl=pt-br) diz que o método `delete()` serve apenas para deletar arquivos. Ainda não é possível deletar pastas, como indica este [fórum do firebase-talk](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/aG7GSR7kVtw).

Comment: É possível então limpar a pasta?

Comment: Também não. Porque o Firebase Storage não tem nenhum método capaz de mostrar todos os arquivos que estão nessa pasta para poder limpá-la. Infelizmente, até agora a única forma de apagar pastas e o seu conteúdo é através da Consola do Firebase ou através da linha de comandos (`gsutil`)

Comment: Pode colocar um exemplo do `gsutil` na pergunta?

Comment: Veja o link do firebase-talk que coloquei na resposta. O post do Kato Richardson mostra um exemplo do gsutil